# Datadome logs api

Tags: logging, bots, cloudflare

I installed datadome on my website protected with Cloudflare and integrated cloudflare workers.
https://docs.datadome.co/docs/cloudflare-worker

How can I access the logs here with api I want to block bad ip addresses on my website
**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/60y27.png)**

**NOT:Datadome does not automatically ban bad ip addresses, it only lists these ip addresses**

I could not find a document where I can access bad ip addresses registered in Datadome dashboard with api. If you know, please share the link with me.